# Python 2.7.10 how to iterate files creation with different names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create a different number of files with Python 2.7.10. The number of them is determined by the i index ( range(X) where X is already been defined) and the name should be like :file1,file2,file3,file4...filei. Here what I was writing:

```
list3 = range(X)
for i in list3:
   # (here I want to add the creation process)
```

Thanks to everyone!!

Comment: At the end of the file I would suggest to use an extension, especially if you are using windows OS :-) This will help you in opening later on the files itself. Ciao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list3 = range(x)
for i in list3:
    with open("File%i" % i, "w") as myfile:
        #do something
```

Comment: Wow! This is awesome! You're a genius!

Answer (score 1):

You can just open files and not write anything to them to create them:

```
for i in range(x):
    f = open("file{}".format(i), 'w')
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The question I guess is a duplicate one. Anyway for instance you can do something like that:

```
for x in range(3):
    with open('File' + str(x) +'.txt','w') as f:
        stringa = str(x) + ' Number of file written inside'
        f.write(stringa)
```

Hope this solve your query. Have a nice day and ciao!